# Set Material Selection Doesn't See Instances

Tags: node-editor

I have a problem: https://youtu.be/-R3pOgoc-g8

In the video you can see some cubes, those are instances.
When I set material after the "instance on points" and use the selection with "index" +"compare = equal", it, instead of picking index of the the instances, uses an index of faces and puts the material on each face instead of the whole cube of index that I chose.

I tried to plug the same selection into the set position node and it worked just as it's supposed to, it moves the whole instance of an index that I picked but for some reason, it doesn't work with set material.

I tried to use the capture attribute and set it to "instances" to specify that I need an index of instances instead of the index of faces but this way it just doesn't work at all.
I'd like to know how I can set material on each instance instead of each face of an instance. Let me know if I should attach the file here.

I have a strong feeling that this is something stupid and easily fixable but I can't figure it out. Would appreciate any help, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: use capture attribute, set to instance, plugin index and compare with result of that capture attribute node. happy bl.

Comment: I tried it, it's 1:20 on a video:
https://youtu.be/-R3pOgoc-g8